# Se puede tener un ng-selected para múltiples select dentro de un ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Estoy trabajando en una tabla, la cual contiene múltiples filas, cada una de ellas tiene un cliente y un estatus correspondiente. Sin embargo, al cargar la tabla, no puedo mostrar el estatus por defecto en un `select`. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes">
    <td>
        <select ng-model="defaultvalue" ng-options="option.value as option.display for option in options">
            <option ng-selected="defaultvalue == option.value" >{{option.display}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si mostraras tu controlador te podría dar más detalles de dónde puede estar tu problema, pero, por lo que estoy viendo, todos tus `selects` utilizan `defaultvalue` como `ng-model` y esta variable según tu código no estaría incluida en cada fila sino que estaría directamente en el `$scope`. Creo que sería más apropiado que utilizaras un `ng-model` diferente para cada `select` y que este estuviera ubicado en cada fila. El siguiente `snippet` te muestra como cada `select` utiliza un `ng-model` diferente y cada uno tiene una opción por defecto aplicada con `ng-selected`:

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.clientes = [
    {name: "Manuel",  defaultvalue: 2},
    {name: "Ricardo", defaultvalue: 1},
    {name: "María",   defaultvalue: 3},
    {name: "Julia",   defaultvalue: 4},
    {name: "Minerva", defaultvalue: 1}
  ];
  
  $scope.options = [
    {display: "Opción 1", value: 1},
    {display: "Opción 2", value: 2},
    {display: "Opción 3", value: 3},
    {display: "Opción 4", value: 4}
  ];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <table ng-controller="MyController">
    <tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes">
      <td>{{cliente.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="cliente.defaultvalue" ng-options="option.value as option.display for option in options">
            <option ng-selected="cliente.defaultvalue == option.value" >{{option.display}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```